# Can Someone Explain Why My Getter Function Doesn't Call?

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code to create a student class and a menu that allows the user to input and display information. Im running into some issues getting my GetName function to call. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Student {
  string FirstName, LastName, Birthday;
  int MNumber, Age;
  float GPA;
  public:
  void GetName(){
    cout << "Please enter your First Name." << endl;
    cin >> FirstName;
    cout << "Please enter your Last Name." << endl;
    cin >> LastName;
    cout << FirstName << ", " << LastName << endl;
  }
};

int main () {
 Student GetName;

  return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: And where do you *call* it? You only create an object called `GetName` and you don't call any method on it.

Comment: `Student x; x.GetName();`

Comment: It is not a good idea to have class methods asking the user for input.  A better design would be to have `main()` gather the input values, and then create the `Student` object to hold those values.

Comment: Rational for above: The resulting object is more versatile.  For example, every time `GetName` is run prompts are written to the screen. This is wasted time and noise in a logfile somewhere if the input is automated. The `GetName` only takes input from `cin`, but what if you find a new use-case where the program needs to read from a file or some other input stream? What if you construct the object, but fail to provide the values necessary to make it useful? Better to make that impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the "Getname" method inside main program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Student {
  string FirstName, LastName, Birthday;
  int MNumber, Age;
  float GPA;
  public:
  void GetName(){
    cout << "Please enter your First Name." << endl;
    cin >> FirstName;
    cout << "Please enter your Last Name." << endl;
    cin >> LastName;
    cout << FirstName << ", " << LastName << endl;
  }
};
int main () {
    Student getName;
    getName.GetName();
    return 0;
}
```